# Trying to convert functional asp:CommandField to asp:LinkButton via asp:TemplateField

Tags: asp.net

I want to take advantage of the breadth of attributes available to a `LinkButton` compared to a `CommandField`.  When calling the code behind method from on click I get this error message:

> CS0123: No overload for 'ViewHandler' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'.

GridView definition:

```
<asp:GridView ID="wc" EmptyDataText="Empty WC table..." runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="WC_ID,PW_ID,R_Qty" 
CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"  
AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="Sorting" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
OnSelectedIndexChanging="ViewHandler" OnPageIndexChanging="HandlePageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvRowDataBound"
OnRowEditing="gvRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvRowUpdating">
```

Orig button...

```
<asp:CommandField ControlStyle-Font-Size="Smaller" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#717171" HeaderText="..." ShowSelectButton="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SelectText="..." />
```

Convert to....

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="..." ShowHeader="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
          <asp:LinkButton style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #717171" ID="Details" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="ViewHandler" CommandName="ViewHandler" Text="..." ToolTip="Click here to see purchase history and notes"></asp:LinkButton> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ViewHandler(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        string WC_ID =wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        string PW_ID = wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        string VIN = wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        string PROD = wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        string W = wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        string SIZE = wc.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[5].Text;
        e.Cancel = true;
        Session.Add(WebConstants.WC_ID, WC_ID);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.PW_ID, PW_ID);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.VIN, VIN);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.PROD, PROD);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.W, W);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.SIZE, SIZE);
        DetailsNavigateMethod.DynamicInvoke();
        HandlePageNavigation(WebConstants.WC_DETAILS, "WC View for WC_PurchaseID-> " + Session[WebConstants.WC_ID].ToString());
    }
```

What do I need to do to make the signature match with the `ViewHandler` method?  I did notice if I switch from `GridViewSelectEventArgs` to `EventArgs` the overload error goes away but then `e.NewSelectedIndex` does not exists...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `OnClick` event handler for a `LinkButton` must have this signature:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

But you are defining it as

```
protected void ViewHandler(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
```

However, you won't have access to e.NewSelectedIndex, obviously. What you can do is change your markup to (notice the `CommandArgument` part):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="..." ShowHeader="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
          <asp:LinkButton style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #717171" ID="Details" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="ViewHandler" CommandName="ViewHandler" CommandArgument='<%=string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",Eval("Prop1"),Eval("Prop2"),Eval("Prop3"),Eval("Prop4")) %>' Text="..." ToolTip="Click here to see purchase history and notes"></asp:LinkButton> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And your code to:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        string [] values = ((LinkButton)(sender)).CommandArgument.Split(new char[]{','});
        //where  values[0] will have WC_ID, values[1]=PW_ID, etc,
        Session.Add(WebConstants.WC_ID, values[0]);
        Session.Add(WebConstants.PW_ID, values[1]);//etc...
        //Session.Add(WebConstants.VIN, VIN);
        //Session.Add(WebConstants.PROD, PROD);
        //Session.Add(WebConstants.W, W);
        //Session.Add(WebConstants.SIZE, SIZE);
        DetailsNavigateMethod.DynamicInvoke();
        HandlePageNavigation(WebConstants.WC_DETAILS, "WC View for WC_PurchaseID-> " +  Session[WebConstants.WC_ID].ToString());
}
```

**Note:**

1. `Prop1, Prop2, etc.` have to be changed to actual property names from your data source.
2. Above code hasn't been tested but that's the idea.

Comment: I do get the jist of this...  The CommandArguments string is being built wrong but I can figure that out - Thanks!